# How to print file content in parts to the screen?

Tags: linux, perl, shell, io

I am trying to store command output into a file (that works fine) and then what I want to do, is to display the file content to the screen.
My problem is that I want it to be displayed in parts (for example 20 lines at a time) and let the user press `[Enter]` or any key to continue to the next part. I was thinking about piping the file content to `more` however it displays the whole file content at once instead of doing it by parts.

Here is my part of the code that is responsible for opening a file, writing to it, and then displaying it on the screen.

```
open FILE, '>', $filename;
print FILE @command;

open FILE, '<', $filename;
while (<FILE>) {
    open MORE, '| more';
    print MORE;
}
close MORE;
close FILE;
```

Comment: If you've already got the output stored in `@command`, just print that out 20 lines at a time. No need to read from the `FILE` you just wrote. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I omitted my first part of the code which is storing ps into '@command', then I create a file and write to it the result of '@command'. How can I display 20 lines at a time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @command = map "output line $_\n", 1..100;

my $page_size = 20;
my $n = 0;

for my $line (@command) {
    print $line;
    $n ++;
    if ($n % $page_size == 0) {
        print "--More--";
        <>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need the `open more` out of the loop:

```
close FILE;
open FILE, '<', $filename;
open MORE, '| more';
while (<FILE>) {
    print MORE;
}
close MORE;
close FILE;
```

or without using more:

```
open my $file, '<', $filename or die("$!");
while (@command) {
    print join("\n", splice(@command, 0, 20));
    <>; 
}
close $file;
```